# Derived Column Transformation Length Error:

Tags: ssis

I am new to SSIS and trying to use the Derived Column Transformation, but after setting up the control flow I get this error:

[image]

I am loading the data from a View and I not sure why the Length and the Data Type columns aren't populated, any suggestion on the reason for error are helpful.

Comment: Did you try to set `Length` to 4000?

Answer (score 0):

In SSIS, "DT_WSTR" cannot have a length greater than 4000.

Here, it tells you that it cannot determine the data type and length because the value exceed the expected range based on the matadata of the column you used.

To see the matedata of your colmns view, you can right click on the source activity and click on "Show advanced editor". In the popup click on "Input and output properties" and see the datatype of your columns:
[image]

If the length of the derived column can be greater than 4000, you have to use "DT_NTEXT" datatype.